# How to use readline with autocompletion and with a custom output stream?

Tags: autocomplete, readline, python-2.x

I try to obtain a kind of shell with autocompletion enabled and with an automatic update on the text printed.

My first idea was to encapsulate the standard output into a custom object and to redirect every attribute access to the original standard output object.
Only the write function is overrided to manage the text updating.
But once the standard output is replaced by the object wrapper, the autocompletion stop to work.

Here is a simple example that try to add a one space prefix, it does not work with python2 but it works with python3 if raw_input is replaced with input.

```
import readline
import sys

class writer(object) :
    def write(self, text):
        sys.__stdout__.write(" "+text)

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == "write":
            return object.__getattribute__(self,name)

        return sys.__stdout__.__getattribute__(name)

def complete(suffix,index):
    return [suffix+"a", suffix+"b", None][index]

if 'libedit' in readline.__doc__:
    import rlcompleter
    readline.parse_and_bind ("bind ^I rl_complete")
else:
    readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")

readline.set_completer(complete)
sys.stdout = writer()

while True:
    print(raw_input(">"))
```

thanks for any help.